# Include img in href (with anchor text) or add a separate href?

Tags: seo, search-engines, images

From the SEO point of view, which one of these two are better ?
Considering this is a classifieds site with around 10 similar listings/links per page.

Separate link for thumbnail and text title

```
<a href="/product.html">
   <img src="/product.jpg" alt="product" />
</a>
<br /><a href="/product.html">product</a>
```

One link that contains both thumbnail and text title

```
<a href="/product.html">
   <img src="/product.jpg" alt="product" />
   <br />product
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The benefit to using a separate link is tracking which link converts better. The image, or product name or title. Using event tracking with Google Analytics you'd be able to see which of the two were clicked on more often and which converted higher.

However if you view Zappos category pages, the image and title of product are both within the `a` tag. This may make it easier and quicker for shoppers to get to the product page

http://www.zappos.com/mens-socks-clothing~1

I doubt the internal links would have much effect on your rankings. There are far more important factors such as content and external incoming links.

Answer (score 0):

It may make a mild difference to how the Page Rank flows around your site, but unless you are doing Page Rank sculpting then both are fine.

If you *are* doing Page Rank sculpting, then both are still fine but you may want to use a "nofollow" tag on one of the links, depending on the linked-to page's priority on the site.

I personally wouldn't worry about the SEO, but would have a preference for the second method simply because there is less repetition in the code, and so less places to change should the link be updated.

Comment: **Never** use nofollow on one of two links to the same destination.  When Google encounters that, it treats them both as if they were nofollowed.  From Google's point of view, if you said you didn't trust the link once, why should they trust it either time?